# Find distance between current location and user input field using button in Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working with a project to find the distance between two places, one is current location and other is user input value using auto-complete text view.

How can I get the correct distance using button click. I got the values without a button click. How can I implement button click?

[image: output with map click listener].

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    MarkerPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    final AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);

    autoCompView.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item));
    autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.search_button);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String location = autoCompView.getText().toString();
            List<Address>addressList = null;

            if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this);
                try {
                    addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Address address = addressList.get(0);
                LatLng dest = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
                lat1=String.valueOf(address.getLatitude());
                lon1 = String.valueOf(address.getLongitude());
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "new Lati and new longi1 "+dest, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(dest).title("Marker"));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(dest));
               // SendDataToServer(unique_id,lat1,lon1);
                //   mMap.clear();
                findPath(point);

            }



        }
    });

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

}

private void findPath(LatLng point) {
  if (MarkerPoints.size() >= 2) {
        LatLng origin = MarkerPoints.get(0);
        LatLng dest = MarkerPoints.get(1);

        // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
        String url = getUrl(origin, dest);
     //   Log.d("onMapClick", url.toString());
        FetchUrl FetchUrl = new FetchUrl();

        // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
        FetchUrl.execute(url);
        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(origin));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16));
    }

}

private void drawMarker(LatLng point) {
    MarkerPoints.add(point);

    // Creating MarkerOptions
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

    // Setting the position of the marker
    options.position(point);
  private String getUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;


    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;


    return url;
}

/**
 * A method to download json data from url
 */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();
        Log.d("downloadUrl", data.toString());
        br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}

// Fetches data from url passed
private class FetchUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try {
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            Log.d("Background Task data", data.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);

    }
}

/**
 * A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format
 */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            Log.d("ParserTask",jsonData[0].toString());
            DataParser parser = new DataParser();
            Log.d("ParserTask", parser.toString());

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            Log.d("ParserTask","Executing routes");
            Log.d("ParserTask",routes.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ParserTask",e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
        String distance = "";
        String duration = "";

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            points = new ArrayList<>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                if(j==0){    // Get distance from the list
                    distance = (String)point.get("distance");
                    continue;
                }else if(j==1){ // Get duration from the list
                    duration = (String)point.get("duration");
                    continue;
                }

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(10);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);

            Log.d("onPostExecute","onPostExecute lineoptions decoded");
            tvDistanceDuration.setText("Distance:"+distance + ", Duration:"+duration);
        }

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        if(lineOptions != null) {
            mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        }
        else {
            Log.d("onPostExecute","without Polylines drawn");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need two Asynctasks... JSON parsing is fine on the UI thread. This code seems more complicated than it needs to be

Comment: ok sir, how can i get distance , using button?

Comment: I think that the `LatLng` or maybe `Location` class has a distance method itself. The button is irrelevant to the actual distance calculation

Comment: @cricket_007 whats the name of the method? I didn't know about that. Is it ```distanceTo``` ?

Comment: i used this tutorial "http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/driving-distance-and-travel-time-duration-between-two-locations-in-google-map-android-api-v2/", in this tutorial there is no button click,only map click is used.

Comment: Here at Stack Overflow we try not to downvote the same person more than once. However, we also expect posters to notice the edits to their questions so they do not keep making the same mistakes. The original version of this question featured urgent begging, which I removed, [because presenting deadlines is not an appropriate way to address volunteers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495). We think this is obvious, but the community discussed it anyway. Your latest question features more of the same.

Comment: Pro tips: please refrain from adding "urgent", "asap", "please help me" and other forms of begging and pleading. We know you need help, and we would rather not have more editing to do! Thanks.

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer or posting your solution. It may help other with the same question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the latitude and longitude of both locations then you can easily calculate the distance between both position. Visit http://www.geodatasource.com/developers/java for more information.

Here is how you can do it in android.

Create a method as following in some class

```
private static double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, String unit) {
        double theta = lon1 - lon2;
        double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = rad2deg(dist);
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        if (unit == "K") {
            dist = dist * 1.609344;
        } else if (unit == "N") {
            dist = dist * 0.8684;
        }

        return (dist);
    }

    /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
    /*::    This function converts decimal degrees to radians                        :*/
    /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
    private static double deg2rad(double deg) {
        return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }

    /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
    /*::    This function converts radians to decimal degrees                        :*/
    /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
    private static double rad2deg(double rad) {
        return (rad * 180 / Math.PI);
    }
```

Then you can use `distance` method

For example distance is static method of Helper Class then

`int distance = Helper.distance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2,"K")`  use "K" for kilometer "N" for

I hope this will help you somehow.

Comment: You should use google map to get position one and position two's coordinates then find the distance with these methods once you get the distance you can show it anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is the method I use to get the distance and time travel from user location to selected location. Add it below your `AsyncTask`:

```
public void getDistAndDuration(JSONObject jObj){
    try{
        JSONArray array = jObj.getJSONArray("routes");
        JSONObject rou = array.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONArray legs = rou.getJSONArray("legs");
        JSONObject steps = legs.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject distance = steps.getJSONObject("distance");
        JSONObject duration = steps.getJSONObject("duration");
        final String textDist = distance.getString("text");
        final String textDur = duration.getString("text");

        Log.i("DISTANCE", ""+textDist);
        Log.i("TIME", ""+textDur);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Call this method in your `ParserTask` in the `doInBackground` method like this:

```
@Override
protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

    JSONObject jObject;
    List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

    try {
        jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

        ////////// HERE //////////////
        getDistAndDuration(jObject);
        //////////////////////////////

        Log.d("ParserTask",jsonData[0].toString());
        DataParser parser = new DataParser();
        Log.d("ParserTask", parser.toString());

        // Starts parsing data
        routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        Log.d("ParserTask","Executing routes");
        Log.d("ParserTask",routes.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ParserTask",e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return routes;
}
```

If you only want to get the distance on button click, declare your `jObject` globally, and call the `getDistAndDuration(JSONObject jObj)` in the click listener of your button. Be sure to call it after you called the `AsyncTask` first.

Hope it helps :)